# is it possible to have a listbox with multi item @ windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

i would like to know if is it possible to have a listbox binded to multiples textbox.
i mean if i click in addButton, i get the content of 5 textbox added simultaneously in the same row (horizontal).
i know its impossible to have more than one stackpanel or datatemplate so i wants to know if is it possible
ty

Comment: Hi, We'll likely need to see the definition/initialisation of your data structure to help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put the new textboxes within the DataTemplate and then add a new empty item to the collection you're binding to:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myLb">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="85" Text="{Binding Field1}" />
                <TextBox Width="85" Text="{Binding Field2}" />
                <TextBox Width="85" Text="{Binding Field3}" />
                <TextBox Width="85" Text="{Binding Field4}" />
                <TextBox Width="85" Text="{Binding Field5}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Using the above with the following code behind works for me.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyListViewModel> myVM;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myVM = new ObservableCollection<MyListViewModel>
                   {
                       new MyListViewModel
                           {
                               Field1 = "A1",
                               Field2 = "A2",
                               Field3 = "A3",
                               Field4 = "A4",
                               Field5 = "A5"
                           }, 
                       new MyListViewModel
                           {
                               Field1 = "B1",
                               Field2 = "B2",
                               Field3 = "B3",
                               Field4 = "B4",
                               Field5 = "B5"
                           }
                   };

        myLb.ItemsSource = myVM;
    }

    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myVM.Add(new MyListViewModel());
    }
}

public class MyListViewModel
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hello matt,i have already try it but it simply didnt work, the second textblock doesnt show. i have made a test with the second textbox having text ="randomString" and nothing :( the listbox is serialized maybe its change smth ty

Comment: @user: How are you adding items to your ListBox (if you could add some code to your question it'd be helpful)? Continuing with @Matt's example, the easiest to do would be to create a `MyDataObject` class that has 5 public string properties - `Field(1-5)`. Then create an `ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>` and assign it to your ListBox's `ItemsSource` property. Now you can just add / remove objects from this collection and the change will make it to your ListBox. Also, `MyDataObject` class will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There are lots of examples for this if you google it.

Comment: hello thx for your help, my listbox is already an observable collecton of dataobject with inotifypropertychanged. if i create a class Myobject, is it possible to bind the values in the listbox ?

Comment: @user569574 I've expanded my answer further to show code behind to work with the xaml included originally. This now shows 2 populated ros when started and the click event adds a blank row.